# How to Remove Search.moviecorner.com Search Bar

Tags: search, virus

I am facing issue in removing Search.moviecorner.com. My browser constantly redirects to Search.moviecorner.com. I want to remove it from Search bar permanently

Comment: Sounds like you loaded up some malware/adware. Download and scan with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) for Mac. No need to purchase anything. My mom gets hit by this stuff all the time, and she knows to run Malwarebytes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this question doesn't seem to be about Apple products or their use.

Comment: What browser? What version of macOS?  What have you tried thus far that failed?  Please help us help you by updating your question with specifics so we can assist you.  As written, it's nearly impossible to tell exactly what the problem is much less direct you to a solution